# 'class QPlainTextEdit' has no member named 'text'

Tags: c++, qt

C:\Projects\QTProjects\SampleProject\mainsample.cpp:18: error: 'class QPlainTextEdit' has no member named 'text'

```
#include "mainsample.h"
#include "ui_mainsample.h"

MainSample::MainSample(QWidget *parent)
: QMainWindow(parent)
, ui(new Ui::MainSample)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainSample::~MainSample()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainSample::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    ui->TxtAns->text(TxtFnum->text().toInt() + ui->TxtSnum->text().toInt());
}
```

What seems to be the problem ?

Answer (score 2):

The error is shown because the following parts

```
ui->TxtAns->text(...)
TxtFnum->text()
ui->TxtSnum->text()
```

each try to call a method called `text()` which does not exist for the class `QPlainTextEdit` which you are using.

Another thing is: Even if there would be a `text()` method, it can only be used to *read* the text, but not for *assigning a new one*.

Assuming all three objects are `QPlainTextEdit`s:

```
ui->TxtAns->setPlainText(              // this method sets the text to TxtAns
    TxtFnum->toPlainText().toInt() +   // this reads the text from TxtFnum
    ui->TxtSnum->toPlainText().toInt() // this reads the text form TxtSnum
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

It means pretty much what it says :)

The `QPlainTextEdit` class does not have a `text()` method. It does have a [`toPlainText()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qplaintextedit.html#plainText-prop) method. Perhaps you meant to use a `QLineEdit` which does have [`text()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlineedit.html#text-prop) method?